# autoscale with memory utilization, alarm metric is in insufficient data state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

we decided to go for memory utilization autoscalling. I created a cloudformation template. we  have a private web server so we have added a proxy details in userdata of launch configuration to download the cloudwatch agent. Ec2 which is created is health and working fine and also we see cloudwatch agent is downloaded. but my alarm metric remain in sufficient data due to which when there is load ,autoscalling is not happening

Launch configuration:

```
 "UserData": {
                "Fn::Base64": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "#!/bin/bash\nmount -av\nexport https_proxy=10.20.10.5:8080\napachectl -k restart\nrpm -Uvh https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/amazon_linux/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm\n/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackId} --resource ASGLaunchConfiguration --region ${AWS::Region} --configsets default\n/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackId} --resource ASGLaunchConfiguration --region ${AWS::Region}\n"
                }
            }
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
                "configSets": {
                    "default": [
                        "01_setupCfnHup",
                        "02_config-amazon-cloudwatch-agent",
                        "03_restart_amazon-cloudwatch-agent"
                    ],
                    "UpdateEnvironment": [
                        "02_config-amazon-cloudwatch-agent",
                        "03_restart_amazon-cloudwatch-agent"
                    ]
                },
                "02_config-amazon-cloudwatch-agent": {
                    "files": {
                        "/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json": {
                            "content": {
                                "Fn::Sub": "{\n  \"metrics\": {\n    \"append_dimensions\": {\n      \"AutoScalingGroupName\": \"${!aws:AutoScalingGroupName}\",\n      \"ImageId\": \"${!aws:ImageId}\",\n      \"InstanceId\": \"${!aws:InstanceId}\",\n      \"InstanceType\": \"${!aws:InstanceType}\"\n    },\n    \"aggregation_dimensions\" : [[\"AutoScalingGroupName\"]],\n    \"metrics_collected\": {\n      \"mem\": {\n        \"measurement\": [\n          \"mem_used_percent\"\n        ]\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "03_restart_amazon-cloudwatch-agent": {
                    "commands": {
                        "01_stop_service": {
                            "command": "/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a stop"
                        },
                        "02_start_service": {
                            "command": "/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m ec2 -c file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json -s"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "01_setupCfnHup": {
                    "files": {
                        "/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf": {
                            "content": {
                                "Fn::Sub": "[main]\nstack=${AWS::StackId}\nregion=${AWS::Region}\ninterval=1\n"
                            },
                            "mode": "000400",
                            "owner": "root",
                            "group": "root"
                        },
                        "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-auto-reloader.conf": {
                            "content": {
                                "Fn::Sub": "[cfn-auto-reloader-hook]\ntriggers=post.update\npath=Resources.ASGLaunchConfiguration.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init.02_config-amazon-cloudwatch-agent\naction=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackId} --resource ASGLaunchConfiguration --region ${AWS::Region} --configsets UpdateEnvironment\nrunas=root\n"
                            },
                            "mode": "000400",
                            "owner": "root",
                            "group": "root"
                        },
                        "/lib/systemd/system/cfn-hup.service": {
                            "content": "[Unit]\nDescription=cfn-hup daemon\n[Service]\nType=simple\nExecStart=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-hup\nRestart=always\n[Install]\nWantedBy=multi-user.target\n"
                        }
                    },
                    "commands": {
                        "01enable_cfn_hup": {
                            "command": "systemctl enable cfn-hup.service\n"
                        },
                        "02start_cfn_hup": {
                            "command": "systemctl start cfn-hup.service\n"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

and metric :

```
 "MemoryAlarmHigh": {
        "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
        "Properties": {
            "EvaluationPeriods": 1,
            "Statistic": "Average",
            "Threshold": 70,
            "AlarmDescription": "Go in Alarm is memory is higher than 70% for 60 seconds",
            "Period": 60,
            "AlarmActions": [
                {
                    "Ref": "ScaleUpPolicy"
                }
            ],
            "Namespace": "CWAgent",
            "Dimensions": [
                {
                    "Name": "AutoScalingGroupName",
                    "Value": {
                        "Ref": "ASG"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanThreshold",
            "MetricName": "mem_used_percent"
        }
    },
```

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Does the IAMInstanceProfile provide the [CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/create-iam-roles-for-cloudwatch-agent-commandline.html) in one of its roles? This policy is necessary to send metrics to CloudWatch. Especially since you are using a proxy I would look into roles and policies first.

Comment: Yes I have attached both cloud watch policy, cloudwatch agent admin policy and cloudwatch server policy. I also eddited the common-config.toml file with the proxy details

Comment: I had read one document where we have to put proxy in common-config.toml file we did that as well. Still our cloudwatch metric stays in insufficient data